# How to show row count in SSRS per grouping on variable group-by value?

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, row-number

Essentially, I'd like to have separate row counts per grouping. I believe I'm supposed to use `RowNumber`. This seems to have been discussed but I'm having difficulty due to the fact that my groupby is not a string constant.

My attempts have lead to something that is similar to :

```
=RowNumber(Parameters!GroupBy1.Value)
```

The SSRS report doesn't load if I have this set as it is.

Row counts per DS work. If instead I use:

```
=RowNumber("NameOfMyDataSet")
```

I'll have row counts successfully, but without resetting per group.

How can I reset the row-count per group if I'm using a variable group-by name?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to set the scope of the function as the name of the group, not the DataSet, something like:

```
=RowNumber("Group1")
```

**Edit after comment:**

As above this is the name of the group created in the report, not any of the values in the DataSet.

In Designer:

[image]

Group properties:

[image]

Comment: This is not very helpful. As my question indicated I do not have the string constant name of the group-by. It is variable and set via parameters.

Comment: @Rail24, as above you need the name defined when you created the group. This is a report object and has a static name.

Comment: Ah. I've been misunderstanding articles all day then. I apologize as this is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.